# Increment the value of a receipt number

Tags: java, database, numeric

In java, say I have a program which checks for the max value in database and increments it by 1 to create my receipt number.

How could I start my first number as 001 and increment it accordingly.

Thus

```
int x = rs.get( sql statement for maximum value).
```

Say `x = 001`

New number to be inserted back should be 002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your variable x is int, so it can't be 001, just 1, but you can make a String to use it elsewhere with formatting:

```
String formattedX = String.format("%03d", x);
```

I suppose, "checks for the max value in database" means to get next value for the Primary Key. To do it, you can use a database sequence ([read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649102/what-is-a-sequence-database-when-would-we-need-it), it's databasespecific so I can't say how to implement it in your case) and everytime you need it, get it's next value. For OracleDB it can be done with this query:

```
SELECT somesequense.nextval FROM DUAL;
```

Or you can use a analytics MAX() functions for your Database, example for Oracle:

```
SELECT MAX(receipt_number) "Maximum" FROM receipts;
```

And then just increment it in your java code. But it's not a good solution, because it can lead to some problems, when you'll get the same value in several transactions.

Comment: Thanks. Using sequence iv discovered is a very good solution. God bless