# How to lock table between read and write operations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, locking

I've a situation where each new record should contain a unique and readable value.
This value has a business meaning for the user and will be handled as a natural id (next to primary key) in our database.

To give you an idea of the value's structure:

```
 - record 1 has business value 'INVOICE_AAA_001'
 - record 2 has business value 'INVOICE_AAA_002'
   ...
 - record 999  has business value 'INVOICE_AAA_999'
 - record 1000 has business value 'INVOICE_BAA_001'
 - record 1001 has business value 'INVOICE_BAA_002'
   ...
```

This business value is created by a factory:

```
class BusinessFactory {

    ...    

    public String createUniqueValue() {
        String lastValue = (String) getSession().createQuery("select businessValue " + 
                                                             "from Invoice as invoice " + 
                                                             "order by businessValue")
                                                .setMaxResults(1)
                                                .setReadOnly(true)
                                                .uniqueResult();    

       // generate new value 

       return newValue;
    }

}
```

The Service layer will call the factory and save a new Invoice:

```
  @Transactional
  public void saveNewInvoice() {
      final String newValue = businessFactory.createUniqueValue();        
      Invoice invoice = new Invoice(newValue);
      invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
  }
```

The problem here is that a situation might exist where trx1 and trx2 read business value 'INVOICE_BAA_002'.
What happens next is that 2 trx's are working with the same value. The trx that first commits will succeed, the 2nd will fail due to a unique constraint exception.

Therefore I need to put a lock on Invoice table when reading out the latest Business value. I think this lock should be active until the new Invoice entity is saved to DB.

How should I do this in Hibernate?

Comment: A sequence can help you. You can create one?

Comment: I'm not aware how to create a sequence. Could you give me some more information about this? Does a sequence prevent 2 concurrent transactions working with the same value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a conflict detection concurrency control mechanism, such a relying on unique constraints or [optimistic locking](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/), you can use pessimistic locking.

You need to have:

1. An `InvoiceSequence` table with an Entity mapped to it
2. This table has only one row, storing the latest invoice sequence value
3. You [acquire an exclusive lock](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-locking-patterns-how-do-pessimistic_read-and-pessimistic_write-work/) on the record:

   ```
   InvoiceSequence invoiceSequence = em.find(InvoiceSequence.class, 1L, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
   ```
4. You increment the sequence using your business logic and modify the entity to store the latest value:

   ```
   String currentSequence = invoiceSequence.getValue();
   String nextSequence = sequenceGenerator.nextValue(currentSequence);
   invoiceSequence.setValue(nextSequence);
   ```

The exclusive lock will prevent both concurrent read and writes too.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I guess I'll have to define some sort of lock time-out to prevent another trx waiting indefinately and to ensure the lock will be released? Maybe I should also add an aspect that automatically retries a failing trx due to lock time-out?

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is a set of integers 1, 2, 3, ... that are generated in order on demand. Sequences are frequently used in databases because many applications require each row in a table to contain a unique value, and sequences provide an easy way to generate them.

One way you can do

```
class BusinessFactory {
public String createUniqueValue() {
    String valueNotUsed = (String) getSession().createSQLQuery("select nextval('hibernate_sequence')");    

   // generate new value 

   return newValue;
}}
```

Comment: The name `lastUniqueValue` is misleading here as the value which you got is already unused one. The `nextval` return next _unused_ value so you can use it directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is nextval('hibernate_sequence') something Hibernate or database specific? Is this function available on all databases regarding to prevent dialects?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649102/what-is-a-sequence-database-when-would-we-need-it

Comment: Once again thanks for your reply. But I doubt if 'nextval' is useful for this situation because I also have to manage alphanumeric positions (AAA, BAA, BBA...) So I think that I really need to read the business value of the latest inserted record and apply a lock.

Comment: You can catch the last inserted to generate letters. And get a new value of the sequence and merge with the letters