# executing a block of stetement at one go

Tags: java, synchronization

I have some block statements which fetches data from database increment it's value by one and again update in database,If am firing 5 requests it's working fine but if I am firing number of request (consider 10) within few seconds(consider 10 to 15 secs) I am getting same value for 2 to 3 request out of 10 request. what is solution so that I can get next value for each request ? I have tried synchronised block but it's not working...!

Comment: Well, without seeing your code, the answer cannot be more than a general one: learn about concurrency in Java, good start is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html), then you can proceed to more detailed [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: It sounds more like it should by synchronized in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **sequences**.

Most database-systems support sequences. The main purpose of a sequence is to give you incremental and unique values.

In a Oracle-database you could query the sql:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mysequnece;
SELECT mysequnece.nextval FROM dual;
```

See [What is a sequence (Database)? When would we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649102/what-is-a-sequence-database-when-would-we-need-it)

Answer (score 0):

You could increment the value at the database level where the update will be atomic.
e.g.

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET logins = logins + 1 
  WHERE id = 12
```

Then you wont need to synchronize the block in the code.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762851/increment-a-database-field-by-1) for more info on database level increments of values